# Limiting non logged in users click a link

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We have a link on the home page and for security reasons, need to prevent a user from clicking the link X number of times in Y minutes. It's a server side link button and I can return a informational message if they exceed the threshold.

However, I am not sure how I could identify the user. Should I use the client's IP address? Can I use session for a non logged in user?

Comment: Are you using the built in webforms membership that comes with ASP.NET?

Comment: Is this for the user's convenience, or is this a security issue (such as DOS)?

Comment: No matter what you use, keep in mind that it can be spoofed. You are getting in an arms race between you and an attacker. *Know your enemy !*

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - We want do to this to prevent security attacks

Comment: @LenielMacaferi - No, not using the membership api. We are using the forms authentication though.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the total clicks using Session.

However, if the user is malicious/clever - he can easily 'lose' the session by refusing to accept cookies, or loading the page without the sessionid (in the case of cookie-less session handling).

Using the IP address might work, but realise that people using the same network might have the same IP address, so you might hit a few people by accident. Again if you're trying to prevent a DDOS - it won't make any difference since they'd have a list of IPs to play with.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using an IP address to identify a user. See: [Is it reliable to use the IP address to identify a user on your website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832724/is-it-reliable-to-use-the-ip-address-to-identify-a-user-on-your-website)

Using a cookie is often the best way to track users. But obviously if this is a security issue then that can be circumvented.

If you are dealing with a potential Denial-Of-Service attack, then I think the only secure option is to require the user to login before allowing him/her to click the link. If this is not a major security issue (it's OK for bad actors to circumvent), then just require the use of cookies for your site and track clicks that way.

---

**EDIT**
Based on your comment, I think you need to implement a secure and meaningful method for the user to login. There is no universal way to successfully and reliably identify a single user (however you may define that). You will need to have the user login and accept cookies (so you can track their session).

This is like trying to prevent kids from ringing your doorbell more than once. Trying to determine who they are from the murky blackness of the web (IP address, etc) is like trying to identify the ringer by having them shout their name at you through the door. You will have to have them present some more meaningful and concrete form of identification which can be attached to them and tracked if you want to have any hope of making that dang doorbell stop.