# PHP or Javascript - How do you set a minimum time between form submits

Tags: php, javascript, forms, time, minimum

Surprisingly, I couldn't find anything relevant on the internet/stackoverflow, while I would think it's often used.

My form is basically a file upload form, and I want to set a minimum time between form submits using Javascript or PHP (PHP prefered), to protect the form from bots etc.

The only thing I could came up with was a cookie/session, but those can be deleted/cleared/modified.

Comment: Disable JavaScript and the check would not matter. You need to control it on the server. Force people to log in and force times that way. Anonymous uploads will be impossible to restrict.

Comment: @epascarello My website would redirect people who's Javascript is turned off, and I could always set a parameter to true using Javascript, and that my PHP Upload script would only let you upload when that parameter was set to true (right?)

Comment: Do you know I do not need a browser to submit my data to your site? Any command line can do it. I can set what ever you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used a simple MySQLi table.

The MySQLi table contained three columns,

1. 'ID' (the User's Login ID),
2. TimesUploaded (Times uploaded within a specified, default 15, amount of minutes),
3. TimeLastUploaded (The time the user uploaded its first of the maximum, *TimesUploaded*, documents)

The Code:

1.Function getuploaduse()

```
function getuploaduse(){
    require('connect.php'); //Connect with the MySQL database
    $theid = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `UploadUse` WHERE ID=\"".$_SESSION['id']."\""));
    if($theid[0] == 0){
        return 'makenew'; //Make a new row
    } else {
        return mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT TimesUploaded,TimeLastUploaded FROM `UploadUse` WHERE ID=\"".$_SESSION['id']."\"")); //Pass on TimesUploaded and TimeLastUploaded
    }
}
```

2.PHP in Upload Page

```
//Set variables
$block = 'false';
$mintime = 15; //A minimum of 15 minutes between $maxuploads
$maxuploads = 3;
$contents = getuploaduse();// [0] => TimesUploaded, [1] => TimeLastUploaded


if(isset($_POST['thetitle'])){ //If users uploads

if($contents != 'makenew'){
    if($contents[0] == $maxuploads){
        $block = (time() - $contents[1]);
        if($block < ($mintime * 60)){
            $block= 'false';
            mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `UploadUse` SET `TimesUploaded`=1,`TimeLastUploaded`='".time()."' WHERE `ID`='".$_SESSION['id']."'"); //Reset
        } else {
            $block = $mintime - round($block / 60);
        }
    } else {
        $block = (time() - $contents[1]);
        if($block >= ($mintime * 60)){
            $block= 'false';
            mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `UploadUse` SET `TimesUploaded`=1,`TimeLastUploaded`='".time()."' WHERE `ID`='".$_SESSION['id']."'"); //Reset
        } else {

            $increased = ($contents[0] + 1);
            mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `UploadUse` SET `TimesUploaded`='".$increased."' WHERE `ID`='".$_SESSION['id']."'"); //Increase
            if($increased == $maxuploads){
                $block = $mintime - round($block / 60);
            } else {
                $block = 'false';
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO UploadUse(ID,TimesUploaded,TimeLastUploaded)   VALUES('".$_SESSION['id']."','1','".time()."')");
}

//Place your upload script here and set $success to something to show your success and not the 'Maximum uploaded'

}

//Block if user doesn't upload (so when he tries to access the upload page)

if($contents != 'makenew' && $block == 'false'){
$contents = getuploaduse();// [0] => TimesUploaded, [1] => TimeLastUploaded
if($contents[0] == $maxuploads){
    $block = (time() - $contents[1]);
    if($block < ($mintime * 60)){
        $block = $mintime - round($block / 60);
    } else {
        $block = 'false';
    }
}
}
```

3.With your uploadform

```
<? if($block == 'false'): ?>
<!-- Your upload form here -->
<?php elseif(isset($success)): ?>
<!-- Success here-->
<?php else: ?>
<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
    <h4>You exceeded the maximum uploads per <?php echo $mintime; ?> min.</h4>
    <p>You may upload maximum <?php echo $maxuploads ?> documents per <?php echo $mintime; ?> minutes. You have to wait for <span class="label label-danger"><span id="updatemin"><?php echo $block; ?></span> minute<? if($block > 1){echo 's';} ?></span>.</p><br />        
  </div>
<? endif; ?>
```

4.In my HTML Header (So when the users is blocked, it will update the minutes remaining)

```
<?php if($block != 'false'):?><meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="60; url=/Upload"><? endif; ?>
```

If you think this code is useful, please vote my (own) answer up, as I did spend time on this code. (I'm a beginner, and to me, this code is something to be proud of, especially since I haven't used tutorials or other answers)

Answer (score 0):

storing the submitter ip you can use:

- memcache key which expires after minimum time
- temp file "flag"
- make life harder for the bot using captcha

Comment: [Would fail if multiple people on same network.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6832808/14104)

Comment: bot fighting without captcha is hard. they can change ip,ua etc. if chances are high that people submitting the form are using the same network don't filter by ip...

Comment: @user831405 Unfortunately, memcache (and memcached) are disabled on my server, and I'm planning on using a captcha, though it's not what I prefer, but was do you mean by `temp file "flag"` (Your second suggestion)?